# How to split the last 2 Strings from each line to replace them repeatedly

Tags: java, split

I am trying to write to file from database where I stored coordinates values.
The file I want to save to is SVG file, the code I was confused with how to replace `moveTo` coordinates and `curveTo` coordinates? Plus  how to repeat C command in each line? The data are stored in database as String in this form

`355.22 632.0771 355.574 631.338 315.228 632.077 
455.22 632.0771 355.574 631.338 335.228 632.077
555.22 632.0771 355.574 631.338 375.228 632.077
655.22 232.0771 355.574 631.338 385.228 632.077
755.22 332.0771 355.574 631.338 365.228 632.077
255.22 432.0771 355.574 631.338 395.228 632.077
155.22 532.0771 355.574 631.338 355.228 632.077`

The last 2 values are for move variable i.e: `move="355.228 632.077";`

and each line is considered as a curve, the curve variable i.e: `curve="355.22 632.0771 355.574 631.338 315.228 632.077";` there are 7 curves in my example.
For example:

```
public class WriteToSVG {

private Formatter f;

public void openFile(){
    try{
        //To Open & create the a File
        f=new Formatter("C:\\demo.svg");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error occured");
    }
}

public void addRecords(){
    try{
        //Add Data to the File
        String str="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n" +
                "<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 14.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 43363)  -->\n" +
                "\n" +
                .....";
        f.format(str);
        String space=" ";
        String fill="003399";
        String fill_opacity="1";
        String strock="none";
        String move = "";
        String[] moveSplit = move.split("\\rs");
        String curve="1022.9594,426.89007 1022.7136,426.30999 1022.5051,425.84922";
        String id="path4044-3";
        String nodeType="cccccccccccccccccc"; 
        f.format("<path%s" +"style="+"\"fill:#%s;fill-opacity:%s;stroke:%s\""+"\nd=",space,fill,fill_opacity,strock);
        f.format("\"M%s",move);//moveTo variable
        f.format( "C%s",curve);//curveTo variable
        f.format("z\""+"\nid=\"%s\""+"\ninkscape:connector-curvature=\"0\""+ "\n sodipodi:nodetypes=\"%s\""+"/>",space,fill,fill_opacity,strock,id,nodeType);
        f.format("</svg>");
    System.out.println("Data added to the File successfully");
      }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error occured");
    }
}
public void closeFile(){
    f.close();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WriteToSVG w=new WriteToSVG();
    w.openFile();
    w.addRecords();
    w.closeFile();
}}
```

How to use split according to the above points, where i want to use the last 2 points from each line ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
final String[] lines = {
    "355.22 632.0771 355.574 631.338 315.228 632.077",
    "455.22 632.0771 355.574 631.338 335.228 632.077",
    "555.22 632.0771 355.574 631.338 375.228 632.077",
    "655.22 232.0771 355.574 631.338 385.228 632.077",
    "755.22 332.0771 355.574 631.338 365.228 632.077",
    "255.22 432.0771 355.574 631.338 395.228 632.077",
    "155.22 532.0771 355.574 631.338 355.228 632.077"
};

for(final String line : lines) {
    final String[] parts = line.split(" (?=[\\d.]* [\\d.]*$)");
    final String[] curves = parts[0].split(" ");
    final String[] moves = parts[1].split(" ");

    // here, curves contains your first four numbers and moves contains the two last ones
}
```

---

***How it works:***

- For **each line**, we split the content in two parts.
- For **the first part**, splitting its content on spaces gives the list of *curve* coordinates.
- For **the second part**, splitting its content on spaces gives the list of *moves* coordinates.

For example, considering the line `"355.22 632.0771 355.574 631.338 315.228 632.077"`:

```
line = "355.22 632.0771 355.574 631.338 315.228 632.077";
// splitting here                      ^
parts = {"355.22 632.0771 355.574 631.338", "315.228 632.077"};

parts[0] = "355.22 632.0771 355.574 631.338";
// splitting      ^        ^       ^
curves = {"355.22", "632.0771", "355.574", "631.338"};

parts[1] = "315.228 632.077";
// splitting       ^
moves = {"315.228", "632.077"};
```

I hope this helps ;)